# How can I debug the code below?

Tags: java

Can smb help why I'm getting NullPointerException in this method? The method should sort the data inside the textfile. Null pointer is in the line

```
r[index] = new Exam(r[i].getFirstName(), r[i].getLastName(), r[i].getID(), r[i].getExamType(), r[i].getScore());
```

```
public static Exam[] collateExams(Exam[] exams)
        {

            Exam[] r = new Exam[exams.length]; 
            int index = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < exams.length; i++)
            {
                if(exams[i].getExamType() == 'm')
                {

                    r[index] = new Exam(r[i].getFirstName(), r[i].getLastName(), r[i].getID(), r[i].getExamType(), r[i].getScore());
                    for(int j = 0; j < exams.length; j++)
                    {

                        if((exams[j].getExamType() == 'f') && exams[i].getLastName().equals(exams[j].getLastName()))
                        {
                            r[index+1] = new Exam(r[j].getFirstName(), r[j].getLastName(), r[j].getID(), r[j].getExamType(), r[j].getScore());
                        }
                    }
                }
                index+=2;
            }



            return r;
        }
```

Comment: You are using array elements **before** you initialize them.  See what happens when both `index` and `i` equal to **zero**.

Comment: I've posted a couple of working examples for you now.  I had an example with multiple loops that you said you couldn't use due to having multiple loops.  Then I put up a multi-dimensional array approach that while not efficient at all matched your criteria.  Even if neither of those is exactly what you need, at least the code worked in both cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to debug your code is by using IDE like Intellij, eclipse, Netbeans etc.

Multiple issues:

- You just defined your array and never initialized it. By default every array element will be null and your are trying to do `r[i].get...` which is why you are getting NullPointerException. Any method call on null object would lead to null pointer exception as is in your case. So you could initialize the array elements from exams array that you got as n input to the method perhaps.
- From the looks from the above code, if you have two exams in your array. Now consider how it will run:

  ```
  Pass 1:
  index = 0
  i = 0
  r[index] = new ... which is fine as index is 0
  index += 2 so now index is 2
  Pass 2:
  i = 1
  r[index] = new ... since you defined r as Exam[] r = new Exam[exams.length]; which means you could just access r[0] and r[1] and now you are trying to set r[2] which is not valid.
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think that

```
r[index] = new Exam(r[i].getFirstName(), r[i].getLastName(),...
```

should be

```
r[index] = new Exam( exams[i].getFirstName(), exams[i].getLastName(),...
```

for copying/recreating another Exam from the input array.

Also, the

```
index += 2;
```

doesn't look right to me.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize an empty Exam-array in the following line:

```
Exam[] r = new Exam[exams.length];
```

Then you try to access the object at index 0 in the first loop iteration, but in the first loop iteration there are no items inside the array r. So you get a NPE:

```
r[index] = new Exam(r[i].getFirstName(), r[i].getLastName(), r[i].getID(), r[i].getExamType(), r[i].getScore());
```

I think you want to read the information passed to the constructor from the array "exams" instead of "r":

```
r[index] = new Exam(exams[i].getFirstName(), exams[i].getLastName(), exams[i].getID(), exams[i].getExamType(), exams[i].getScore());
```